# What can be the reason of the silence of the MediaStream received with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I have a problem related to WebRTC

Peers connect, exchange Offers and Answers, the `'track'` event is executed, MediaStream and MediaStreamTrack arrive, respectively, but nothing happens when trying to play them...

What could be wrong here?

I try to play them through `new Audio().srcObject = stream`.
Just in case, I checked that the streams received via `getUserMedia({ audio: true })` are played in this way, so the problem is not with the playback method...

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple reasons that can't be easily troubleshooted without a running example or the code.

You can start from [WebRTC samples](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/audio/) or use [turnkey WebRTC apps](https://github.com/videowhisper/VideoCall-HTML5-Videochat-PHP) that already work in your project.

Comment: great suggestion